# How do I set the home page for Safari on the iPad2?

Tags: safari, ipad, preferences

This is driving me crazy .

I'm trying to set the Home page on the iPad.

The instructions I've seen indicate there should be a bar at the bottom of the browser with an arrow. There isn't. There also isn't a Home Page button.

I just updated the latest OS release few weeks ago.

Any ideas?

Comment: For reference, typically the "arrow" icon is at the bottom of the *iPhone's* screen. On iPad it is typically on the upper left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of HomePage in Safari for iPad. Sorry

You can go to your favorite website, use the "arrow" icon and press the "On home screen" button, that will create an icon on your homescreen which will launch that webpage in safari when you press it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the desired home page, press on the box with the arrow next to the URL box, select "add to home page" then before saving it rename it "Safari" then click on that every time you want to use the internet and it will open as your home page every time

Answer (score 0):

There's an arrow coming out of a box near the cloud button.
Then click Add To Home Screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. This does not appear to answer the question as the poster was looking to set the home page within Safari, not add a site to the home screen.